# Sufficient condition for a matrix to be diagonalizable and similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, similar-matrices

my question is about diagonalizable matrices and similar matrices.

I have a trouble proving a matrix is diagonalizable.

I know some options to do that:

Matrix $A$ $(n \times n)$, is diagonalizable if:

- Number of eigenvectors equals to number of eigenvalues.
- There exists an invertible matrix $B$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that: $D=B^{-1}AB$.

But i have a trouble to determine it according the second option, Do i really need to search if there exists an invertible matrix $B$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that: $D=B^{-1}AB?$

I really sorry to ask an additional question here: If a matrix has a row of $0$'s (one of its eigenvalues is $0$), That matrix is diagonalizable?

in general, given a matrix, how do i know if is a diagonalizable matrix? Are there some additional formulas to do that?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: The second option is, more or less, the _definition_ of diagonalization, and diagonalizability. As for the additional question, the zero matrix is trivially diagonalizable.

Comment: @Arthur: The OP didn't ask about the zero matrix, he asked about a matrix with a row of zeros. That's insufficient to be diagonalizable.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld That is one way to interpret the question. I read it as "can a matrix with a row of zeroes be diagonalizable?" I might've been wrong, but there it is.

Comment: If the roots of the minimal polynomial are all simple roots, then the matrix is diagonalizable. Rmk: all the roots of the minimal polynomial are eigenvalues of the matrix and if $\chi (t)=(t-\lambda_1)^{\mu_1}...(t-\lambda_k)^{\mu_k}$ the minimal polynomial is $\varphi (t)=(t-\lambda_1)^{\eta_1}...(t-\lambda_k)^{\eta_k}$, where $\eta_i \le \mu_i$ $\forall i=1,...,k$ (I'm assuming that the matrix is $\mathrm{n}\times \mathrm{n}$). I wrote you this property because is really useful for problems and exercises.

Comment: If a matrix $A \in \mathrm{M}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable, then $\exists$ $C \in \mathrm{Gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $D=C^{-1}AC$, where $C^{-1}$ is a matrix whose columns are eigenvectors and they appear with the same order of the eigenvalues on the diagonal of $D$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First a comment**

The wording *Number of eigenvectors equals to number of eigenvalues...* is confusing. If $A$ has a non zero eigenvector then $A$ has an infinite number of eigenvectors (providing you work in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ for example). A proper wording would be $A$ has a basis of eigenvectors.

**If a matrix has a row of $0$'s (one of its eigenvalues is $0$), That matrix is diagonalizable?**

The implication "If a matrix has a row of $0$'s" then "that matrix is diagonalizable" is not true.
The matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ is an example. The only eigenspace is $\mathbb F e_2$ were $e_2$ is the second vector of the canonical basis (and $\mathbb F$ the field of the vector space).

**Some equivalent conditions for a matrix $A$ to be diagonalizable**

- The sum of the dimensions of its eigenspaces is equal to the dimension $n$ of the space.
- $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix.
- Its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors.

Comment: The statement that a matrix with a row of zeroes is never diagonalisable is clearly wrong, just consider $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Toffomat I haven't say that it is never diagonalizable! I meant that the implication $P \implies Q$ is not true where $P$ is "a matrix has a row of $0$'s and $Q$ is "it is diagonalizable". I'll precise that is my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If a $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then it is automatically diagonalizable. Otherwise, compute the dimension of each eigenspace. The matrix is diagonalizabel if and only if the sum of these dimensions is $n$.

Concerning the sentence “There exists a matrix $B$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that: $D=B^{−1}AB$”, well… That's basically what being a diagonalizable matrix *means*.

Comment: "If a matrix has a row of zeros then, yes, it can be diagonalizable." But it seems the OP is asking whether having a row of zeroes *implies* being diagonalisable.

Comment: You are right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The statement "*matrix $A$ ($n×n$), is diagonalizable if: number of eigenvectors equals to number of eigenvalues*" is not correct.

We would say that a matrix $A$ ($n×n$), is [**diagonalizable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterization) **if and only if** the sum of the dimension of eigenspaces is equal to $n$, that is **if and only if** for any eigenvalues the algebraic multiplicity is equal to the geometric multiplicity.

When a matrix is diagonalizable, of course, by definition the diagonal form is [**similar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to the original matrix. Note that similarity holds, more in general, also with the [**Jordan normal form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) when the matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Existence of Jordan normal form supposes that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ splits into linear factors in the field $\mathbb F$ over which the vector space is defined.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks for the pointing out, even if I can't relate that to the OP. Bye!

Comment: Just a comment as the OP has not precised the field over which the vector space is defined. Jordan normal form may not exist.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ah ok, thanks again!

Comment: The Jordan Normal Form may not exist. The correct test for the similarity of two  matrices (over a field $\mathbb{F}$) is that they have the same Rational Canonical Form.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm not aware about those kind of generalization but I believe to your words in faith. Bye :)